# Plotar gráficos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, gráfico

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e necessito gerar um gráfico a partir de dados passados por um formulário, contudo não desejo plotar o gráfico completo de uma vez, e sim fazer uma espécie de animação, onde o gráfico é desenhado aos poucos. 
 
 Já pesquisei e vi algumas bibliotecas JS para plotagem de gráfico, como o Google Charts, porém não encontrei nenhum material de como desenhar um gráfico aos poucos.

Comment: https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-column-chart/

Comment: [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) é uma boa lib também.